# [MIDL]How to use interfaces declared in c/c++ headers in idl files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, idl, midl

`ID2D1RenderTarget` is an interface defined in `d2d1.h`. I want to use it in my IDL interface like this:

```
interface IXXX : IUnknown {
    HRESULT XXX([out, retval] ID2D1RenderTarget **_ppRT);
}
```

`d2d1.idl` is not included in the SDK and I can only get `d2d1.h`(no d2d1.tlb, either).

I have tried including `d2d1.h` using cpp_quote:

```
cpp_quote("#include <d2d1.h>")
```

It raised:

```
error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting a type specification near "ID2D1RenderTarget"
```

Then I added a typedef:

```
typedef struct ID2D1RenderTarget ID2D1RenderTarget;
```

The error changed to this:

```
error MIDL2011: unresolved type declaration : ID2D1RenderTarget [ Type 'ID2D1RenderTarget' ( Parameter '_ppRT' ) ]
```

I have also tried adding `cpp_quote("#define D2D_USE_C_DEFINITIONS")` before the include but it made nothing.

So what should I do to use `ID2D1RenderTarget` in my IDL files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIDL compiler needs an IDL file to refefence, or a type library. Direct2D interfaces are not available any of these methods. They are not available through registered type library either - you only have them as C++ headers in Windows SDK.

One way would be to duplicate definitions in your IDL/TLB file, however I would recommend to accept the fact that interfaces are undefined in IDL domain and use `IUnknown` there instead. A type library consumer can always do `IUnknown::QueryInterface` for the interface in question.

```
interface IXXX : IUnknown 
{
    HRESULT XXX([out, retval] IUnkown** ppRendererTargetUnknown);
}
```